# Multisteps Webform loses current page when refreshing browser

Tags: webforms, forms

I've created a Webform with three steps. When I refresh the browser (F5) on step 1 and 2, I correctly remains in the same page.

If I do the same in step three, I go back to step 2. For ALL the steps > 2, when I refresh the page I go back to step 2.

I tried to change same Webform settings ("Allow cookies for tracking submissions" and "Automatically save as draft between pages"), but with no results.

I'm using an anonymous user to browse the Webform's pages.

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: You need to give us more information. What version of Drupal are you using? Which version of webform? Are you using any other modules?

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose I use [Multi-step forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/mforms) module. This does all the heavy lifting for you. It allows you to use a session storage so if the page gets refreshed or the browser gets closed, it saves the current step.

**Multi-step forms:**

> Mforms module is a set of tools that help to create advanced multistep forms in Drupal. It can be modified and extended so a developer has full control of the way how individual form steps will be handeled, how and where will data be between form steps stored, which step will follow, how form controls will act and how the output will be displayed.
>
> The main differences from existing multistep solutions for Drupal are robustness, flexibility and extensibility. You can even dynamically change the steps sequence and jump from one step to another regardless of their order.
>
> Read [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1603920).